# Ubuntu Chromium bookmark icons blank

Tags: ubuntu, bookmarks, chromium

Ever so often I load Chromium and it refuses to load my profile.  Now that doesn't happen any more but since then it refuses to load the icons for my bookmarks which, if you look at the attached pic, is my only way of identifying which icons do what (other than hover for tool-tip, or actually pressing the icon button).   The other possible variable is that the bookmarks are meant to sync with Google sync - I'm not sure if that is a factor.

How do I restore the icons to my bookmark bar?

[image]

Chromium version: Version 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 (144678)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, ok.  This is similar to fecub's idea, but it's a different file involved:

```
1. delete ~/.config/chromium/Default/favicons
2. restart computer
```

The second step seems to be important, merely closing Chromium didn't work.  Presumably killing it properly would work also.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: http://tech-knowlogy.blogspot.de/2009/07/recover-deleted-bookmarks-in-google.html 
instruction is for windows, but it's the same. in linux you find it in,

/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but it didn't solve it for me.